# Unexpected "FilterPolicyScope" Requirement in AWS SNS Subscription - Serverless Invalid Parameter, but the Parameter doesn't exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless, serverless-framework, amazon-sns

I have an SNS FilterPolicy, and according to AWS docs, no filterPolicyScope is required. If it is not set, the default is MessageAttributes, it says. And this is how I have had it for quite some time without issue, but now it is an issue even though I have made no changes. Now I get this error suggesting that FilterPolicyScope IS required. But I can't figure out why.

An error occurred: DynamoConsumerSubscription - Invalid parameter: FilterPolicyScope: Invalid value [null]. Please use either MessageBody or MessageAttributes (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: d374f542-3f41-5626-a65f-a9cb71c4277b; Proxy: null).

I just have this:

````
      Type: "AWS::SNS::Subscription"
      Properties:
        Endpoint:
          Fn::GetAtt: [DynamoWorkConsumerQueue, Arn]
        Protocol: sqs
        RawMessageDelivery: true
        TopicArn: !Sub "arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${self:custom.config.DomainBusArnName}"
        FilterPolicy:
          "hyperloop.work.env":
            - "testing-event-management" ...```
````

Answer (score 1):

This has been raised as a bug and raised to **P2** - reported Mar 27 and still **Open**:

- [aws-sns: When using filterPolicy, stack fails with: FilterPolicyScope: Invalid value [null]. Please use either MessageBody or MessageAttributes](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/24804)

Workaround (from comments):

> As a workaround, we just commented out the sns subscription resource (so it can get deleted) and then redeployed with the correct subscription and filter to recreate it. Avoids a stack deletion as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

When I encounter these quirks I take a tour of the AWS docs to see if something has been updated in one place (like the CDK or API docs) and not updated in the CloudFormation docs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sns-subscription.html#cfn-sns-subscription-filterpolicy aka CloudFormation does seem to say that it's not required and there is a default value.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering-apply.html#message-filtering-apply-cli aka the CLI seems to require it even though CF has a default value.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering-apply.html#message-filtering-apply-sdks  aka the SDK does not seem to require it

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_SetSubscriptionAttributes.html the API does not seem to require it as it also has a "default" value of MessageAttributes.

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-sns-samples/blob/master/templates/SNS-Subscription-Attributes-Tutorial-CloudFormation.template is an example CF template and it sets FilterPolicy but not FilterPolicyScope

I have no idea what is going wrong. I'd guess this is a bug.